# Как сделать стрелки направления как на картинке в Elementor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elementor

Как сделать стрелку которая на что то направляет? Желательно в Элементоре.
Вот примеры:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите кто может, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

1. Поставьте виджет «Иконка с текстом» на нужном месте страницы

[image: Иконка с текстом]

2. В разделе иконка, выбирете загрузить svg. Соответственно выберете файл со стрелочкой, [допустим такой](https://www.flaticon.com/ru/free-icon/double-right-arrow_50621?term=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8&page=1&position=65&page=1&position=65&related_id=50621&origin=search)
3. Выберите расположение текста слева и напишите его.

[image: подсказка]